# Retrieve items on Order Magento 2

Tags: magento2

My objective is to send an order to our backend system when a order is placed within our Magento 2 instance.

The code to send the order object is working.  My question is what is the optimum approach to retrieve `item` data (e.g. `price`, `subtotal`, `total`, `sku`, etc.).

I'm using the following to retreive the order and items.

```
$orderId = $this->_order->load($order);
$billing = $orderId->getBillingAddress();
$items = $orderId->getAllItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
        $itemPrice = $item->getPrice();
        $itemSku = $item->getSku();
}
```

Is iterating through `$items` to get price, sku, etc. the best way or is there a Magento2 `collection/method` I should be using?

Thanks

Comment: Does `print_r(orderId->getAllItems())` output all the items?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
```

You done it using objectManager

Comment: Use of object manager is not encouraged in Mage 2

Comment: Does print_r(orderId->getAllItems()) output all the items?

Answer (score 32):

The correct way to load Order object (which will carry the items info in itself) is via Repository objects.

Inject the order repository in your constructor

```
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    ....
}
```

and use in required method as:

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
// var_dump($item->getData());
}
```

To know more about Repository Objects: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories

Comment: upvoted for the correct way of using dependency injection! Should have been marked as the answer.

Comment: should use  `$order->getAllVisibleItems()`

Comment: It depends on your requirement, whether to use `getAllVisibleItems()` vs `getAllItems()`

Comment: Does print_r(($order->getAllItems()) output all the items?

Answer (score 10):

below i code which will help you to get order items (i called in Block class)

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->order = $order;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }



    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getOrderItems()
    {
        $order=$this->order->load(1);

        return $order->getItems();

    }
}
```

if it works accept the answer which will helps others

Comment: In case others come by and try and get this working but can't, I was not able to load the order using `load(1)`. But i was able to get the order information to load using `loadByIncrementId($orderId)`.

Answer (score 10):

If you use

```
$order->getAllVisibleItems()
```

Instead of

```
$order->getAllItems()
```

You will get better results

---

**More Explanation :**

If you take a look at sales_order_item table you'll see that there are two rows for each item in the order, one of them with useless data and the other one with the data that you'd probably need. Well if you use **getAllItems()** you'll get those two lines, but if you use **getAllVisibleItems()** you'll get only the rows with the useful data. I hope this does help you!

Comment: "Better" how? That's a bit vague.

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific, if you take a look at sales_order_item table you'll see that there are two rows for each item in the order, one of them with useless data and the other one with the data that you'd probably need. Well if you use getAllItems() you'll get those two lines, but if you use getAllVisibleItems() you'll get only the rows with the useful data. I hope this does help you!

Comment: Does print_r(orderId->getAllItems()) output all the items?