# How to get all items of product purchased in Magento 2?

Tags: event-observer, order-items

I would get information on **all items of product** ***purchased***.

I proceeded by this way but I can not have any information on all items of product purchased :

```
 <?php

namespace MyTestSpace\productsPurchased\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use MyTestSpace\productsPurchased\Logger\Logger;

class OrderTracker implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $_logger;
    public function __construct( Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }
    
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

            $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();
            $allItems = $order->getAllItems();

            $this->_logger->info('OrderId -> '. $orderId);

            $itemArry = [];
            foreach($allItems as $item){
                $itemArry[]= $item;
            }

            $this->_logger->info('OrderAllItem -> ', $itemArry);

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            $this->_logger->info($th->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

In my log file (OrderTracker.log) I obtient "*OrderId*" but not '***OrderAllItem***'!

Here is an example

> [2020-06-19 15:15:40] OrderTrackerLogger.INFO: *OrderId* -> **000000181** []
> [] [2020-06-19 15:15:40] OrderTrackerLogger.INFO: *OrderAllItem* ->
> ["**[object] (Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item\Interceptor: {})**"] []

Can anyone show me how can we get the OrderAllItem ?
Thanks

Comment: you want to Retrieve items on Order ??? If Yes follow this code `$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();` >> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96237/retrieve-items-on-order-magento-2

Comment: Hi @MohitPatel : I tried it but I have this error :
'undefined property: MyTestSpace\productsPurchased\Observer\Tracker::$_objectManager'

Comment: this error say to you are not load this class

Answer (score 0):

```
__construct(\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory) {
$this->orderFactory = $orderFactory
}
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
       // Get Order Order id.... non increment..
       $order = $this->orderFactory->create();
       $orderDetail = $order->load($orderId);
       $orderDetail->getAllItems() 
       ////   code...
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I don't have orderID, I don't know orderId.
Why, I do not have this commandId, I explain by more information :
When a client buy some article, I must find the information of this order, by the event `sales_order_place_after`, and I want to sent at the API of our provider.
So I tried your code like this :

Comment: Hi @Pankaj
: I tried it butI can not find : here is response : **OrderTrackerLogger.INFO: No such entity with orderId = [] **

Answer (score 0):

So I tried your code like this :

```
namespace MyTestSpace\productsPurchased\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use MyTestSpace\productsPurchased\Logger\Logger;

class OrderTracker implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $_logger;
        public function __construct( 
                Logger $logger,
                \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory) {
            $this->_logger = $logger;
            $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        }
                
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

            $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();
            
            //Argument 2 passed to Monolog\Logger::info() must be of the type array, string given, 
            //$this->_logger->info('OrderID -> ', $orderId);
            $orderIdArry = [
                'OrderID' => $orderId,
            ];
            
            $this->_logger->info('OrderID -> ', $orderIdArry);
            
            // old one 
            //$allItems = $order->getAllItems();
            $orderFactory = $this->orderFactory->create();
            $orderDetail = $orderFactory->load($orderId);
            $allItems = $orderDetail->getAllItems();


            $itemArry = [];
            foreach($allItems as $item){
                $itemArry[]= $item;
            }

            $this->_logger->info('OrderAllItem -> ', $itemArry);

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            $this->_logger->info($th->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I find "orderId' but I have not any information in my following variable : itemArray.
here is result :

> [2020-06-22 20:58:59] OrderTrackerLogger.INFO: OrderID ->  {"OrderID":"000000185"} []
> [2020-06-22 20:58:59] OrderTrackerLogger.INFO: **No such entity with orderId =  []** []
> Could you help me ?